# Angular client application failing to resolve address for backend service from docker container

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run angular frontend and golang backend application using docker containers
they are created successfully but when frontend is trying to make any http call to backend service it is failing with

GET http://backend:8080/questions net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

and from inspecting it show that frontend application is makeing request to
Request URL:
http://backend:8080/questions
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./question-paper
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=questions
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_HOST=database
      - DB_PASSWD=root
      - DB_USER=root
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: questions
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3806:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/  # Check the path to init.sql
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  my-db:
```

and my angular code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Questions } from '../model/question-model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class QuestionService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  GetQuestions(): any {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://backend:8080/questions');
  }
}
```

backend code

```
func main(){
    mux := mux.NewRouter()
    handle := h.CORS(
        h.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"}),
        h.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"}),
        h.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Content-Type", "Authorization", "Origin", "Accept"}),
    )
    mux.HandleFunc("/questions", handlers.GetQuestions)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handle(mux))
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h61rA.png)

can someone help with this why the request is failing,
I can across some solution that say to use ip address of backend service in the http url i don't think that's good choice

Comment: frontend is downloaded from the server and the code itself is being run on the client - outside of docker. it is impossible to make it work with just docker means. instead, you should pass backend url to the client in the environment configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You client-side app doesn't have access to the Docker internal DNS (GET http://backend:8080), read about it [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-docker-desktop-networking-works-under-the-hood/).

You can use a reverse proxy like ngnix or manage the url with enviroment-based approach like:

Development: environment.ts (`ng serve`):

```
export const environment = {
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8080'
};
```

Production: environment.prod.ts (`ng build --prod`):

```
export const environment = {
  apiUrl: 'http://myapi.com'
};
```

Now instead of hard coding your api url you can refer to the environment:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

export class QuestionService {
  private baseUrl = environment.apiUrl; // Use apiUrl from environment

  getQuestions(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}/questions`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shahar Shokrani
The environment variable solution seems to be working, and thank you  for sharing the blog